# How to override default foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have `has_many` and `belongs_to` association between two models as below:

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
 self.primary_key = 'id'
 has_many :rights
end

class Right < ActiveRecord::Base
 self.primary_key = 'id'
 belongs_to :section
end
```

The SECTION table has ID and SECTION_ID column as well. The above  code associates Right to the Section via the ID column in the section table. I want it to associate through the SECTION_ID column. how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: on second read I think I misunderstood your question, you actually want to relate to a field other than the primary key in the Section table? It's not very common, hence my misunderstanding.

You need to use `:primary_key => 'field_name'` instead of `:foreign_key`

```
belongs_to :section, :primary_key => 'section_id'
```

Comment: Yes Matt. I want to relate to a field other than the primary key. I did try as you said above by specifying the foreign key but that didn't work

Comment: That worked. So even though, I have defined in the Right Model that the primary key is `id`, does it override it at the time of association?

Comment: The default behaviour of `belongs_to` just uses 'id' for the primary key, take a look at the options here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
 self.primary_key = 'id'
 has_many :rights
end

class Right < ActiveRecord::Base
 self.primary_key = 'id'
 belongs_to :section, :foreign_key => "section_id"
end
```

Comment: I tried this but it still associates through the same "ID" column

Comment: This answer, like mine, has misunderstood your question. The OP is trying to build a relationship that uses a non-primary-key field in the Section table.

Comment: Rahul,We normally associate two table with section_id matually.